# How to get certains values from Eloquent collection?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have an Eloquent collection (already executed query) and I need to do some things with two items from this array so I need to use `only` or `pluck` methods but they dont  return what I need...

```
$orders = Order::with('parts')->paginate(50);

$orders[0]->parts->lists('name'); // Returns names
$orders[0]->parts->lists('custom_name'); // Returns custom names

$orders[0]->parts->only(['name', 'custom_name']); // Returns nothing
$orders[0]->parts->pluck(['name', 'custom_name']); // Returns no values
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `only` method returns the items in the collection with the specified keys. Since Colllection keys are not those column names you specified but simple incrementing numbers you won't get result by using `only` method.

The `pluck` method retrieves all of the collection values for a given key.

so You must use

```
$orders[0]->parts->pluck('name', 'custom_name');
```

insted of

```
$orders[0]->parts->pluck(['name', 'custom_name']);
```

remove those `[ ]` and it should work fine.

Comment: If I remove brackets from `pluck` I get some yabadabadoo... http://i.imgur.com/aI954F4.png

Comment: I guess you can do it one by one then. `$orders[0]->parts->pluck('name');`    `$orders[0]->parts->pluck('custom_name');`